# How to make select option field using laravel and axios jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, axios

I had one database json value

```
$fos = ToFieldOfStudy::where('parent_id', -1)->get();
return response()->json($fos);
```

MyJson ouput :

```
[{
    "id": 7,
    "value": "Business Administration",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "value": "Engineering",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "value": "Medical",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "value": "Medicine",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 12,
    "value": "Accountancy",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 13,
    "value": "Actuarial Science",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 14,
    "value": "Administrative Office Technology",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 15,
    "value": "Aging Studies",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 16,
    "value": "Agriculture",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 17,
    "value": "Air-Conditioning & `Refrigeration",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 18,
    "value": "Aircraft Maintenance Technology",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 19,
    "value": "American Sign Language",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 20,
    "value": "American Studies",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 21,
    "value": "Animation Engineeering",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 22,
    "value": "Applied Geography",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 23,
    "value": "Architectural / Construction Technology",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 24,
    "value": "Architecture",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 25,
    "value": "Art Education",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 26,
    "value": "Art History",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 27,
    "value": "Arts",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 28,
    "value": "Auto Body Repair",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 29,
    "value": "Automatic / Manual Transmission",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 30,
    "value": "Automotive Air-Conditioning Systems",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 31,
    "value": "Automotive Electrical Systems",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 32,
    "value": "Automotive Technology",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 33,
    "value": "Aviation Airframe Structure / Systems",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 34,
    "value": "Aviation Powerplant Theory / Systems",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}, {
    "id": 35,
    "value": "Aviation Systems",
    "parent_id": -1,
    "is_active": 1
}]
```

in my view.blade.php file i tried code like this :

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="field_of_study[]"]', function () {
       url = "{{route('getfieldofstudy')}}";
       const data = {
           'fos' : $(this).val()
       }
       $(this).parent('.input-group').nextAll('div.input-group').remove();
       axios.post(url, data).then(response =>{
           var sel = '<select class="form-control input-sm" name="field_of_study[]">';
           var opt = [];
           if (!$.isEmptyObject(response)) {
               $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                   opt.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
               });
           }
           if (opt.length > 1) {
               sel += opt.join() + '</select>';
               $('.fos').append('<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 input-group pad-top5">' + sel + '</div>');
           }
       }, 'json');
   });
  //  /*----------Field of Study end----------------*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

anyone tell what am doing wrong..? that selection box shows but values are not displaying.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</option>` ?

Comment: don't consider this code snippet

Comment: try it with `response.data` not just `response`!!

Comment: now its working ..fine thankyou bro

Comment: `console.log(response)`  also check the `key` and `value`,

Comment: but selection box again and again creating 

if (opt.length > 1) {
               sel += opt.join() + '</select>';
               $('.fos').append('<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 input-group pad-top5">' + sel + '</div>');
           }

Answer (score 0):

The wanted Json is wrraped inside the `data` on the response object :

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="field_of_study[]"]', function () {
       url = "{{route('getfieldofstudy')}}";
       const data = {
           'fos' : $(this).val()
       }
       $(this).parent('.input-group').nextAll('div.input-group').remove();
       $('#field_of_study').remove();
       axios.post(url, data).then(response =>{
           var sel = '<select class="form-control input-sm" id="field_of_study" name="field_of_study[]">';
           var opt = [];
           if (!$.isEmptyObject(response.data)) {
               $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
                   opt.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
               });
           }
           if (opt.length > 1) {
               sel += opt.join() + '</select>';
               $('.fos').append('<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 input-group pad-top5">' + sel + '</div>');
           }
       }, 'json');
   });
  //  /*----------Field of Study end----------------*/
});
```

Comment: but in this one error is there am select this created option it creates new selection box again and again selection option creating

Comment: Did you added `id="field_of_study"` to the select as i did in the answer ?

Comment: my laravel form like this type :

{{ Form::select('field_of_study[]', $field_of_studies, $key, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}

Comment: in this case add also the idthere like this : `{{ Form::select('field_of_study[]', $field_of_studies, $key, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'field_of_study')) }}` !

Comment: yaa ok bro , but second selection option is there na  i can't select any value

$key  ==> shows error i removed this $key

opt.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');  => i make like this then only that values coming bro